# DTLS `HelloVerifyRequest`/`HelloRetryRequest` in WolfSSL

Tags: denial-of-service, dtls, wolfssl

The cookie exchange initiated by `HelloVerifyRequest` described in [section 4.2.1 of RFC 6347](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6347#section-4.2.1) is essential to DoS-protection in DTLS. Unless I'm overlooking something, the WolfSSL documentation does not really describe how to enable this cookie exchange with its DTLS implementation.

The closest I can find is the function [`wolfSSL_send_hrr_cookie`](https://www.wolfssl.com/doxygen/group__Setup.html#ga1817c18aa34a0999ab976b27f7abebf5), about which the manual states:

> This function is called on the server side to indicate that a
> HelloRetryRequest message must contain a Cookie. The Cookie holds a
> hash of the current transcript so that another server process can
> handle the ClientHello in reply. The secret is used when generting the
> integrity check on the Cookie data.

As far as I understand, the `HelloRetryRequest` (compare `HelloVerifyRequest`) is TLS 1.3 terminology. DTLS 1.3 is not finalized. How does one enable and control the DTLS 1.0/1.2 cookie exchange in WolfSSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DTLS Hello Cookie is enabled by default. The wolfSSL server code uses the callback function `EmbedGenerateCookie()` in the file src/wolfio.c to generate the cookie per the recommendation in [RFC 6347 §4.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6347#section-4.2.1).

TLSv1.3's hrr_cookie is something else unrelated.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that clarifies a lot! Follow-up question: At what stage of for example [this basic server setup](https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl-examples/blob/master/dtls/server-dtls.c) does the cookie exchange happen? During `wolfSSL_accept`?

Comment: It happens as a part of the state machine backing `wolfSSL_accept()` and `wolfSSL_connect()`.